# Android BLE setReportDelay()

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to implement a BLE scan app where i want to list all the devices nearby in a single scan rather than getting one BLE device at a time.

I read from the Android Documentation that i can use setReportDelay() in the Scan Setting Builder to delay the scan results and to use the BatchScanResults() to get a batch/list of devices found.

However when i try to use the setReportDelay() in the Scan Settings builder the scan does not start at all and i get the following error.

```
04-13 16:03:19.887    8454-8454/com.example.sasnee_lab2.sasbeacon D/BluetoothLeScanner﹕ could not find callback wrapper
```

Here is my StartScan function with Scan Settings

```
public void startScan(BluetoothLeScanner scanner)
{
    ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName(null).build();

    ArrayList<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
                    filters.add(filter);

    ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER).setReportDelay(1l)
                                .build();

    Log.i(TAG,"The setting are "+settings.getReportDelayMillis());
    scanner.startScan(filters,settings,BLEScan);


}
```

And here is the Scan Callback.

```
  private ScanCallback BLEScan = new ScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {

            Log.i(TAG,"The batch result is "+results.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {

            Log.i(TAG,"******************************************");
            Log.i(TAG,"The scan result "+result);
            Log.i(TAG,"------------------------------------------");
        }


        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
        }


        }


    };
```

Please let me know if i'm doing anything wrong in the implementation here.
And thank you.

Comment: Do you remember if you found a solotion? If so, how did you solve it?

Comment: I couldn't manage to find out a solution using Android API's so i had to use a workaround for this.  Basically i stored the Scan Results one after the other in List and after a predefined time A Timer Task would be scheduled within which i had a function to process the available List of Scan Results.

Comment: Thanks. Well, yes, I am working on a workaroun directly reading the scanResult byte array too.

Answer (score 2):

You must check whether your hardware supports scan batching through [BluetoothAdapter.isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported()). If this returns false then you should not attempt to set a report delay.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

**Java**

```
boolean f = adapter.isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported();
if (!f) builder.setReportDelay(0) else builder.setReportDelay(1)
```

**Kotlin**

```
val f: Boolean = adapter.isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported
if (!f) builder.setReportDelay(0) else builder.setReportDelay(1)
```